# How can I pursue academic side interests during my PhD?

Tags: graduate-school

I've come out of undergrad (during COVID, too) with a degree in science, unsatisfied with my general knowledge and work ethic outside of the sciences. I especially regret not pursuing a minor in a humanities field (COVID depression, lack of connection over Zoom, and my **laziness** especially really interfered with that and really did not even make me think of this). Is there a way I can pursue this interest further in graduate school? I am going to attend a liberal arts school for a degree in STEM but I really want to somehow make up for this loss and grow in an area outside of the sciences, because I feel like a very "flat" person right now.

Comment: Ask the school.  Where I went to graduate school, I was allowed to register in courses in other departments.  (Of course do not do it so much that it interferes with your main studies.)

Comment: It's often possible to attend classes without officially registering for them (but with the permission of the instructor).

Comment: I think @AndreasBlass's comment is exactly on-point: if you don't demand resources from people, you can sit and listen to what they have to say. In fact, it does often happen (in math, too, in not-necessarily-"applied" grad courses I teach...) that "outsiders" have very insightful questions! :) So I don't discourage "outsiders" asking questions, at all. Indeed, "insiders" should be _able_ to cogently answer questions from supposedly-amateurish "outsiders", one might think. :)

Comment: Oop, forgot that, in some countries/unis, non-paid attendance is supposedly strictly prohibited. It is my impression that this is _not_ the case in Germany, though, for example. In the US, I have the impression that it is most typical that the Central Admin "strictly prohibits" people from listening without paying. Even "auditing" (not for credit or grade...) requires a fee. At the same time, in math, in the U.S., in upper-division or grad courses, I'm not aware of anyone who'd enforce such an externally-imposed rule. Especially, at publicly-funded places???? :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I was definitely planning to audit courses. But I really want to dig deeper (i.e., project work? I really feel like I missed out not doing a senior thesis for a major/minor in a humanities during undergrad). I really want to make this happen in grad school...